# Javascript - check data one by one - Jquery post()

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

On my local server, everything works fine, but when I upload the scripts to my web server and run the script, I get a php - mysql error message: Too many connections.

I'm trying to insert a delay to `$.post();` function but I don't know how.

```
var videoArrays = new Array();

videoArrays[0] = '34hgfj23rj';
videoArrays[1] = '2kj4mfwjmhkg';
videoArrays[2] = '23kjrmkf4ekjf';
...
videoArrays[152] = '3ok4jtmfj324hfh';

for(var i in videoArrays){
   $.post('get_data.php', { v_data : videoArray[i] },
   function(data){
      if(data == 'exists'){
         alert('Data exists in data base !');
      }
      else alert('Invalid data !');  
   });
}
```

I get the error, because I open / close many connections in less than 3 seconds ( 152 different connections ) !

I need to add a delay, but where or how... I don't know.

Comment: Probably stating the obvious, but why not keep the connection open, run all the code and close it afterwards, by posting the videoArrays in one request.

Comment: I basically agree with @PaulGrimshaw - you should have your API on the server accept a list of names, and it should return a map indicating which ones are or are not available. (Yes sorry I am still working on my first cup of coffee :-)

Comment: I don't close the connection with mysql ( 'get_data.php' ), I only included the 'config.php' for connection.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it with jQuery, but with regular javascript, you can attach a load event listener to your POST request. You could listen for a response then iterate on to the next request.

'ajaxrequest.addEventListener('load', handleload, false);'

Answer (score 1):

You need to create some sort of queue, so you can control how many requests are active at one time. An example of a queue is found here:
[How can I make batches of ajax requests in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986458/how-can-i-make-batches-of-ajax-requests-in-jquery)

and here:
[Queue ajax requests using jQuery.queue()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785724/queue-ajax-requests-using-jquery-queue)

and here:
http://gnarf.net/2011/06/21/jquery-ajaxqueue/