# jQuery.when() doesn't seem to be waiting

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need to make a server side call when a user does something in the DOM (click a checkbox, select a dropdown, etc.  This is the series of events:

1. User clicks a checkbox (or something)
2. A spinner fades in and the UI becomes unavailable
3. The server side call is made, and gets back some JSON
4. A label in the UI is updated with a value from the JSON
5. The spinner fades out and the UI becomes available again

The problem I'm having is that 4 and 5 often get reversed, and the spinner fades out sometimes 2 or 3 seconds before the label is updated.

I'm trying to use .when() to make sure this isn't happening, but I don't seem to be doing it right. I've been looking at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29607893/wait-till-functions-with-ajax-calls-finish-execution-in-jquery), and this one, and [jquery's own documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/).

Here's where I'm at right now...

```
function UpdateCampaign() {
    $('#overlay').fadeIn();
    $.when(SaveCampaign()).done(function () {
        $('#overlay').fadeOut();
    });
}

function SaveCampaign() {
    var formData =
        .... // get some data
    $.ajax({
        url: '/xxxx/xxxx/SaveCampaign',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json', 
        data: { FormData: formData },
        success: function (data) {
            var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
            .... // update a label, set some hidden inputs, etc.
        },
        error: function (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    });
}
```

Everything works correctly.  The server side method is executed, the correct JSON is returned and parsed, and the label is updated as expected.

I just need that dang spinner to wait and fade out until AFTER the label is updated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue is because you're not giving `$.when()` a promise. In fact you're giving it `null`so it executes immediately. You can solve this by returning the promise that `$.ajax` provides from your `SaveCampaign()` function like this:

```
function SaveCampaign() {
    var formData = // get some data

    return $.ajax({ // < note the 'return' here
        url: '/xxxx/xxxx/SaveCampaign',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json', 
        data: { FormData: formData },
        success: function (data) {
            var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
            // update a label, set some hidden inputs, etc.
        },
        error: function (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Bam! That did it!  Thank you.  I'll mark as answer when it lets me in 10 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I know its answered by Rory already. But here's mine promise method, it works fine always and instead of using success and error uses done and fail

```
 var jqXhr = $.ajax({
    url: "/someurl",
    method: "GET",
    data: { 
      a: "a"
  });
//Promise method can be used to bind multiple callbacks
  if (someConditionIstrue) {
    jqXhr
    .done(function(data) {
      console.log('when condition is true', data);
    })
    .fail(function(xhr) {
      console.log('error callback for true condition', xhr);
    });
  } else {
    jqXhr.done(function(data){
      console.log('when condition is false', data);
    })
    .fail(function(xhr) {
      console.log('error callback for false condition', xhr);
    });
  }
```

Or if I want a common callback other than conditional ones,  can bind directly on jqXhr variable outside the if-else block.

```
 var jqXhr = $.ajax({
    url: "/someurl",
    method: "GET",
    data: { 
      a: "a"
  });

  jqXhr
  .done(function(data) {
    console.log('common callback', data);
  })
  .fail(function(xhr) {
    console.log('error common back', xhr);
  });
```