# ajax loading before document despite using when().then() function with leaflet JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, leaflet

Here is what the console reads:
***Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addTo' of undefined***

I am currently working with leaflet JS and before the page loads, there is quite a number of Ajax calls going on so that the website can render the acquired data for the user.

I have used two particular methods to synchronize certain ajax calls which rely on the previous. One method is passing the next ajax call into the complete function, whilst another is the when().then() function

The objective with the function below, which is called with the window.onload method, is to determine the users location using the javascript navigator, set the map, and proceed with the ajax calls as mentioned above.

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    //Pre-loader Jquery
    if ($('#preloader').length) {
        $('#preloader').delay(200).fadeOut('slow', function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    }
    //Determine users location, initiate leaflet map, synchornised ajax calls to retreive country core information
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((success) => {
        const crd = success.coords;
        onLoadLat = crd.latitude;
        onLoadLng = crd.longitude;
        currentMap = L.map('map').setView([onLoadLat, onLoadLng], 5);
        mapTileLayer.addTo(currentMap);
        $.ajax({
            url: "libs/php/openCage.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: {
                latLng: onLoadLat + "+" + onLoadLng
            },
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHRs) {
                iso_a2 = data["results"][0]["components"]["ISO_3166-1_alpha-2"];
            },
            complete: function() {
                //Retreive GeoJson file, mark polygon and set initial map for to reflect user location
                $.ajax({
                    url: "libs/php/getCountryBorder.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    data: {
                        countryCode: iso_a2
                    },
                    success: function(geoData, txtSt, jq) {
                        //Reference details of existing country for further API's and functionality
                        nameOfCountry = geoData["properties"]["name"];
                        //Use the index to target the array and create polygon border on map
                        targetMapData = L.geoJSON(geoData, {
                            style: borderStyle
                        });
                        targetMapData.addTo(currentMap);
                        currentMap.fitBounds(targetMapData.getBounds(), {
                            padding: [50, 50],
                        });
                    },
                    complete: function() {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "libs/php/keyCountryInfo.php",
                            type: "POST",
                            dataType: "JSON",
                            data: {
                                country_code: iso_a2
                            },
                            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                                capitalCity = data["capital"];
                                currencyCode = data.currencies[0].code;
                                coordinates = [...data.latlng];
                                $("#timezoneList").empty();
                                $("#countryName").text(data["name"]);
                                $("#region").text(data["region"]);
                                $("#sub-region").text(data["subregion"]);
                                $("#countryFlag").attr("src", data["flag"]);
                                $("#population").text(numeral(data["population"]).format(0, 0));
                                $("#capital").text(data["capital"]);
                                $("#timezoneList").text(data["timezones"][0]);
                            },
                            complete: function() {
                                $.when(**getPopularCities()**, getCityWeatherList(), getWikiEntries(onLoadLat, onLoadLng), getGeoNameId(), getCountryImages(), getPublicHolidays(), getLatestExchange(), populateSelect()).
                                then(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                                    infoEasyBtn.addTo(currentMap);
                                    wikiEasyBtn.addTo(currentMap);
                                    currencyEasyBtn.addTo(currentMap);
                                    covidEasyBtn.addTo(currentMap);
                                    newsEasyBtn.addTo(currentMap);
                                    weatherEasyBtn.addTo(currentMap);
                                    airportMarkers.addTo(currentMap);
                                    cityMarkers.addTo(currentMap);
                                    siblingMarkers.addTo(currentMap);
                                });
                            }
                        })
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    })
});
```

within the onload function above, is the getPopularCities() method, which is where the issue is. I have set markers to be shown on the map, but there is one group of markers which do not load, from within that function

**Get Popular Cities Method**

```
function getPopularCities() {
    let cityPopulation = [];
    cityMarkers = new L.MarkerClusterGroup();
    if (mainLayer) {
        currentMap.removeControl(mainLayer);
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: "libs/php/getCountryCities.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: {
            getCountryIso: iso_a2
        },
        success: function(success, textStatus, jqXHRs) {
            $("#top10CityTable").empty();
            let cityList = success["cities"]; //grab all the cities from the response
            //create an array in global variable named cityPopulation, to contain all the markers
            cityList.sort((a, b) => {
                if (a["population"] > b["population"]) {
                    return -1
                } else {
                    return 1
                }
            })
            cityList.forEach((element, index) => {
                let formatedPop = numeral(element["population"]).format(0, 0);
                //depending on how many citys have returned, title the heading accordingly
                if (cityList.length < 10) {
                    $("#top10CityHeading").text("Major Cities")
                }
                if (cityList.length >= 10) {
                    $("#top10CityHeading").text("Top 10 Most Populated Cities");
                }
                //stop index at 9 to get data of top 10 most populated cities for modal section
                if (index <= 9) {
                    $("#top10CityTable").append(`<tr><td>${element["name"]}</td><td>${formatedPop}</td></tr>`)
                }
                cityMarkers.addLayer(L.marker([element["latitude"], element["longitude"]], {
                    icon: populatedCities
                }).bindPopup(`<h3>${element["name"]}</h3></br>Population: ${formatedPop}`));
            })
            //create a new overlay prop/value pairing in the global overlays variable
            overlays["Major Cities"] = cityMarkers;
        },
        error: function(text, xh, errorThrown) {
            console.log(errorThrown);
        },
        complete: function() {
            let siblingsMapArr = [];
            siblingMarkers = new L.MarkerClusterGroup();
            $.ajax({
                url: "libs/php/getCountrySiblings.php",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "JSON",
                data: {
                    countryGeoId: geoNameId
                },
                success: function(success, textStatus, jqXHRs) {
                    $("#countrySiblings").empty();
                    let siblingsArr = success["geonames"];
                    siblingsArr.sort((a, b) => {
                        if (a["population"] > b["population"]) {
                            return -1
                        } else {
                            return 1
                        }
                    })
                    let top10Sib = siblingsArr.slice(0, 10);
                    top10Sib.forEach((element, index) => {
                        let formatedPop = numeral(element["population"]).format(0, 0);
                        let rank = index + 1;
                        siblingMarkers.addLayer(L.marker([element["lat"], element["lng"]], {
                            icon: citySiblings
                        }).bindPopup(`<h3>${rank}. ${element["countryName"]}</h3><br/>Population: ${formatedPop}`));
                        $("#countrySiblings").append(`
                            <tr>
                            <td>${element["countryName"]}</td>
                            <td>${formatedPop}</td>
                            <td>${element["lat"]} / ${element["lng"]}</td>
                            </tr>`)
                    })
                    overlays["Top 10 Siblings (By Population)"] = siblingMarkers;
                },
                complete: function(success, data, jq) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "libs/php/getAirports.php",
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "JSON",
                        data: {
                            countryCode: iso_a2
                        },
                        success: function(success, txtStatus, jqXHR) {
                            let airportsArr = [];
                            airportMarkers = new L.MarkerClusterGroup();
                            const airportsList = success["data"];
                            airportsList.forEach((element) => {
                                airportMarkers.addLayer(L.marker([element["location"]["latitude"], element["location"]["longitude"]], {
                                    icon: airportIcon
                                }).bindPopup(`<h3>${element["name"]["original"]}</h3></br>ICAO: ${element["icao"]}</br>Elevation: ${element["elevationFeet"]}<br/>Classification: ${element["classification"]}`));
                            })
                            overlays["Airports"] = airportMarkers;
                            mainLayer = L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlays);
                            mainLayer.addTo(currentMap);
                            airportMarkers.addTo(currentMap);
                            cityMarkers.addTo(currentMap);
                            siblingMarkers.addTo(currentMap);
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
        }
    })
}
```

The markers saved in the variable airportMarkers and cityMarkers appear on the map as well as the leaflet control panel, but the siblings markers do not.

So Im guessing the safe bet is that it is not bringing the data back in time before the page loads? Does anyone have a solution for this or perhaps I have done something wrong in my code?

Comment: You need to return the promise from the functions called by $.when  ->  `$.when(popularCities(), ...`  function popularCities() { .. return $.ajax(...`

Comment: Does this help: [understanding $.when](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280699/jquery-when-understanding)

Comment: Somewhat, yes...but in my case I have multiple ajax calls within the popularCities function, so where does the return go? Should I be returning each one? I have just attempted that but same situation. If anyone can provide an example for my scenario it would be greatly appreciated.